# Local storage for events when click button X Close on window chat box?

Tags: javascript, html

I am a novice, now, I am learning HTML5.

I am buiding a window chat box using CSS. Now I want it to function like facebook'chatbox. Specificly, when I click the button "X" on the window chat box on tab1 it will also close on tab2,tab3,tab4,....tab n of the browser.

Also I would like it to operate the same for hiding the window.
I think I will need to use local storage for my problem, but don't know how to do it
Please help me !

Comment: What actually you wanna store to local storage in your case??

Comment: This is actually going to require using some server-based messaging technologies. Your page instances don't know the others exist.

Comment: I want all action : close, open, hide...any thing of window chat occur simultaneously on multi tabs of brower when client click !.  So what I can use ?

Comment: Do you use facebook ? when open facebook on multi tabs and chat with someone, if you click close window chat on tab1 then tab the rest will close !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Create a database and some tables for it. You will definitely need a table where you store the users. You will need other tables to store user status. When a user is logged in, that user will be associated with the user table and the status table(s) having a foreign key to the user table.

Step 2: You need to develop a service on server-side which will handle post requests. These requests will either update the status or ask for the latest status.

Step 3: On client-side, you will need to do polling to repeatedly get the latest status.

Step 4: Whenever the status changes, refresh your UI components.

Step 5: Handle UI events. For instance, when you click on the x, a status update should be sent to the server that the tab needs to be closed. Other tabs will get the latest status when the next polling request gets a response and then the UI will be refreshed.

Easier said than done, but these are the steps you need to perform.

Comment: Thankyou so much ! The problem seems quite complex ><

Comment: @SilencerIce, yes, indeed. But, in fact this complex problem can be divided into 5 simpler steps. If you study a few tutorials and find the answer to each sub-problem, then you should be able to solve the issue and you have learned quite a lot in the meantime. All steps are pretty standard, so you will find a lot of online resources to help you. If my answer solves your problem, then you might consider accepting it, so later people will see that this is indeed a solution to the problem.

Comment: If you'd like to avoid polling there are also websockets which don't have the same big overhead as POST requests.